How do I reduce the time to read parquet files with pandas and futures
Python version: 3.11.8
Goal: Read 1.000 parquet files from Amazon bucket faster.
Approach: I am using the libraries boto3 and pandas to read the parquet files. I could retrieve the files sequentially. However, I want to reduce the time reading the parquet files by using a parallel execution with the library concurrent.futures. For that reason, I decided to implement the ProcessPoolExecutor, but I got stuck because I do not know how to create my project to implement it. This is my current attempt:
I have two scripts. The first script will read the parquet files and the second script will transform or manipulate all the received data.
script1.py
from boto3 import Session
from pandas import DataFrame,concat, read_parquet
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import wait

def retrieve_s3_bucket(bucket_name: str, 
                       access_key_id: str,
                       secret_access_key: str,
                       prefix: str):
 ### some code to retrieve objects from S3
return objects

def read_parquet_file(object) -> DataFrame:

    buffer = BytesIO()
    object.Object().download_fileobj(buffer)
    
    df_object = read_parquet(buffer) 
    return df_object

def get_data_from_bucket(objects,
                          columns_to_delete: list,
                          columns_to_format: list,
                          restaurant_ids: list) -> DataFrame:

  
  list_dfs = []

  with ProcessPoolExecutor(2) as exe:
    # submit tasks and collect futures
    for object in objects:
      df_object = exe.submit(read_parquet_file(object),object)
      if df_object.empty:
        print("Empty")
      else:  
        list_dfs.append(df_object)
    
    # wait for all tasks to complete
    print('Waiting for tasks to complete...')
    wait(list_dfs)
    
  data = concat(list_dfs,ignore_index=True)

  return data

# protect the entry point
if __name__ == '__main__':
  # start the process pool
  get_data_from_bucket()  

script2.py:
from script1 import get_data_from_bucket, retrieve_s3_bucket

def main(bucket_name: str,
                    access_key_id: str, 
                    secret_access_key: str, 
                    prefix: str) -> str:
  
  try:
    
    data ={}

    objects = retrieve_s3_bucket(bucket_name, access_key_id,secret_access_key,prefix)
    
    df = get_data_from_bucket(objects,
                              columns_to_delete,
                              columns_to_format,
                              list_restaurants)

   ## some addtional operations to do with df 

  except Exception as e:
        
    logging.error(str(e))
    data['error_message'] = str(e)
    data['stack_trace'] = print_exc()
    
  finally:
    return dumps(data)

I am getting the following error during execution:

An attempt has been made to start a new process before the current
process has finished its bootstrapping phase

How should I include the concurrent.futures in my project and to handle properly errors during the reading?. Forgive me if I am doing something wrong but I am pretty new with concept of parallelism.
UPDATE:
To reach my goal, I have a Virtual Machine with the following configuration:
CPU 2.59 GHz
Memory 32 GB
Sockets: 1
Virtual processors: 8
I do not know, if concurrent.futures will be a suitable approach here.

as a first step you need to figure out what is your bottleneck. From the way your question is phrased, my first guess would be network latency, as in you sequentially wait on boto3 to respond, correct? In that case, actually a single process using ThreadPoolExecutor would be more straightforward to implement - in that case you never need to worry about inter-process communication (IPC) since your threads all share the same memory, such has module-level variables.

Depending on what you're trying to do, going through pyarrow's Tabular Dataset might allow you to greatly speed up reading as they will automatically handle this parallel execution. But this only works if the parquet files you're retrieving are of the same schema, which I assume they are, since you are concatenating them.

@Michel Mueller: Yes, I guess the network latency is my bottleneck. After reading some post, I found that the better approach , as you mentioned, is ThreadPoolExecutor. The issue, I am dealing with, is how to implement ThreadPoolExecutor, having in mind that my main function in the script2.py will be call first and then it will be invoke the functions in script1.py. How to protect the entry point here or it does not matter?.

@sergioMoreno: I wouldn't worry about memory protection as much in python as I would in other languages, thanks to how the GIL works. Essentially, once you're in the interpreter, only one thread executes at any given time. This gives you out of the box atomicity for many common operations. Generally, if you don't change any global state you should be fine. you just put your work in an iterable and give to executor.map, and get a list of results back. That list you can then combine however you need.
edit: just to clarify - outside the interpreter, e.g. network requests, still run parallel
